# How to get Bluetooth working on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, bluetooth, broadcom

I have the [BCM423142](https://www.broadcom.com/products/wireless/wireless-lan-bluetooth/bcm43142/) chip on my laptop, recently I've installed Arch Linux (Antergos) and downloaded the `linux-headers` and `broadcom-wl-dkms` packages from AUR.

WiFi works perfect but Bluetooth doesn't, it only appears as powered off in the gnome-panel.

[image: screen capture]

I have this output from the dmesg | grep Bluetooth command:

```
[   12.376925] toshiba_bluetooth: Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device driver
[   15.655590] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   15.655611] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.655614] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.655616] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.655621] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   18.325428] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   18.373084] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   18.373088] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   18.373094] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   26.432140] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
```

I have this output from lsmod | grep blue

```
bluetooth             487424  12 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,btusb
toshiba_bluetooth      16384  0
rfkill                 20480  8 toshiba_bluetooth,bluetooth,toshiba_acpi,cfg80211
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
```

I have this output from the bluetooth command:

```
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
```

I've already tried with this [Installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Installation) and this [Configuration via the CLI](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Configuration_via_the_CLI) and none works.

Comment: Found this. but it is not trivial. <http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu/632348#632348

Comment: @Bahamut : Any new drivers will add on new kernel release.You should read which kernel release he used it for broadcom bluetooth driver.Read the result of  # lsmod command

Comment: Did you know how many lines of source code for kernel 4.x?Almost 5 million lines of souce code for kernel 4.x.Some very old drivers removed from new kernel release.Compiled kernel 4.x need almost 15 GB free space.

Comment: It's not a Problem from the driver, but  firmware-problem. I found something in git maybe easier to handle. <https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I use Arch Manjaro (Gnome).
I solved it (more or less) using the "Fn" + "Wireless key".
It works like a "on/off" for the bluetooth too.

Like your pictur, with Bluetooth window on screen:
First I made "off", then "on" with the keyboard and right after the second action the Bluetooth works fine again.

I hope works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the firmware.
You can find it right on AUR:

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/bcm43142-firmware/

Then reboot.
As check, run the previous command `dmesg | grep Bluetooth`; you will notice more lines and above all, one stating something like *"BCM43142 firmware.hcd Patched"*

**NB:** the above linked AUR package is chipset-specific; please be sure to install the proper package, or it will be worthless

Answer (score 0):

The answer from `@user192526` in the comments in answer is correct and worked for me on Arch Linux.

Install this: https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware

Answer (score 0):

For sure you need to install the **missing** bluetooth drivers. In my case that I have a Dell Studio 1555 laptop and when I enter the command in a terminal:

```
journalctl -b | grep Bluetooth

Jun 14 18:48:47 sherko kernel: usb 3-1.3: Product: Dell Wireless 370 Bluetooth Mini-card
Jun 14 18:48:48 sherko kernel: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Jun 14 18:48:48 sherko kernel: Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Jun 14 18:48:48 sherko kernel: Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Jun 14 18:48:48 sherko kernel: Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Jun 14 18:48:48 sherko kernel: Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Jun 14 18:48:48 sherko systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jun 14 18:48:49 sherko bluetoothd[695]: Bluetooth daemon 5.58
Jun 14 18:48:51 sherko systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jun 14 18:48:51 sherko systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Jun 14 18:48:51 sherko kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Jun 14 18:48:51 sherko kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Jun 14 18:48:51 sherko kernel: Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Jun 14 18:48:51 sherko bluetoothd[695]: Bluetooth management interface 1.19 initialized
Jun 14 18:51:16 sherko kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Jun 14 18:51:16 sherko kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Jun 14 18:51:16 sherko kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Jun 14 18:51:30 sherko systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth management mechanism...
Jun 14 18:51:31 sherko systemd[1056]: Starting Bluetooth management applet...
Jun 14 18:51:31 sherko systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth management mechanism.
Jun 14 18:51:31 sherko systemd[1056]: Started Bluetooth management applet.
Jun 14 18:51:31 sherko systemd[1056]: Starting Bluetooth OBEX service...
Jun 14 18:51:31 sherko systemd[1056]: Started Bluetooth OBEX service.
```

By installing missing drivers `Bluez-hid2hci` the problem resolved after first reboot.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem; I tried to turn it on from the settings windows, but it did not work. So I tried this in the terminal: `systemctl start bluetooth`

It works now!